# Depth First Traversal relationship between nodes of G and DFT

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Let G be an undirected graph. Consider a depth-first traversal of G, and let T be the resulting depth-first search tree. Let u be a vertex in G and let v be the first new (unvisited) vertex visited after visiting u in the traversal. Which of the following statements is always true?

(A) {u,v} must be an edge in G, and u is a descendant of v in T

(B) {u,v} must be an edge in G, and v is a descendant of u in T

(C) If {u,v} is not an edge in G then u is a leaf in T

(D) If {u,v} is not an edge in G then u and v must have the same parent in T.

=========================================================================

> Correct answer is (C)

But I'm stuck at (B), I'm not getting any counter example for (B)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following graph (which is in fact a tree).

```
G := (V, E) where
V := {a, u, v} and E := {{a,u}, {a,v}}.
```

A depth-first traversal in `G` can visit first `a`, then `u` and finally `v`. At the point where `u` is visited, `v` is the next unvisited node. However, `{u, v}` is not an edge in `E`, hence statement `(B)` is false.

Comment: How v is descendant of u? v is descendant of a, right?

Comment: @MicroLegions Yes, exactly. `v` is _not_ a descendant of `u` but of `a`, nevertheless `v` is visited immediately after `u`.

Comment: then how option (B) is false, as v is not a descendant of u and there's no edge in (u,v) in G. at least one of them has to be true. I mean, is there a case where (u,v) is an edge in G, but in T v is not a descendant of u or you can show that v is a descendant of u but (u,v) is not an edge in G, that would be the counter examples.

Comment: Sir, I'm not following you, I understand that (u,v) is not an edge in G, but then v is also not a descendant of u. So, what am I missing? Okay, can you please tell an example for (C) and (D)

Comment: Option (B) is false because `{u, v}` is not an edge in `G`. The cases you describe in your comment cannot occur. I understand the statement (B) in such a way that in particular it states that `{u, v}` is an edge in `G` if `v` is visited immediately after `u` is visited; however, this is not generally true.

Comment: @Condor Can we say, that they have mentioned (u,v) is an edge in G. Now, If (u,v) is an edge and it's an undirected graph therefore (v,u) is also an edge. Point being, since (u,v) is an edge in G therefore they can only be **SIBLINGS** in DFS tree and never have **descendant relationship**

Comment: @MicroLegions No, the situation you describe is impossible. If `{u, v}` is an edge in `E` and `v` is visited immediately after `u`, then `v` is a descendant of `u` in `T`.